# Why does the compiler complain about function ambiguity here?

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to run some sample code from the book "Accelerated C++" (A. Koenig, B. Moo) (§8.2.2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

template <class In, class X>
In find(In begin, In end, const X &x)
{
    while (begin != end && *begin != x) {
        ++begin;
    }

    return begin;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;

    v.push_back(5);
    v.push_back(32);
    v.push_back(42);
    v.push_back(7);

    cout << *find(v.begin(), v.end(), 42) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The `find` function appears like this in the book; the `main` function I wrote myself.

Both clang++ and g++ won't compile this. It seems as if they are complaining that my `find` function introduced an ambiguity with `std::find`. However, I never used `using namespace::std;` nor `using std::find;` in the code, so the compiler shouldn't even be allowed to use `std::find` if it was included. What's going on here?

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/0SZQ7)

Comment: What versions of clang++ and g++ are you using? Can you give us the error message you are getting? What compiler options are you using?  I tested this with g++-4.6.2 and g++-4.7.0 and didn't have any issues.

Comment: Note g++ 4.6.3 does give an error if we add `#include <algorithm>`.

Comment: Apple clang version 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.58)—i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've tripped over "Koenig lookup" (yes, the same Koenig, so you'd think he'd spot the problem), aka "ADL".

Suppose for a moment that via an indirect include, `<algorithm>` has been pulled in.

If `std::vector<int>::iterator` (the type of the argument) is a class in namespace `std`, then `std::find` is a match for your call even though you never "used" it, so the call is ambiguous.

If `std::vector<int>::iterator` is `int*`, then `std::find` is not a candidate and the call is not ambiguous.

Either way is a valid implementation of `std::vector`, and it's also implementation-defined whether or not either `<iostream>` or `<vector>` includes `<algorithm>`. So your code isn't portable, but implementations are pretty much incapable of diagnosing the portability issue unless the code actually fails on that implementation.

In more typical cases of ADL, the function or function template in the associated namespace is a better candidate (more specific) than the one in the namespace that the caller inhabits or "uses", so ambiguity is avoided. But your global `find` is basically identical to `std::find`, so that doesn't apply.

http://ideone.com/Cskur:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace foo {
    struct Foo {};

    /* same as the one we'll define later */
    template <typename T>
    void func(T) {
        std::cout << "namespace function template\n";
    }
    /* this would be a better match
    void func(Foo) {
        std::cout << "namespace function\n";
    }
    */
}

template <typename T>
void func(T) {
    std::cout << "global function template\n";
}

int main() {
    foo::Foo f;
    func(f);
}
```

Result:

```
prog.cpp:19: error: call of overloaded ‘func(foo::Foo&)’ is ambiguous
```

Conclusion: it is somewhat dangerous to use names from `std`, even in other namespaces.

Or if you prefer: defining names from `std` in other namespaces may mean that callers need to be careful. The difference is mostly a matter of who fixes the bug when it happens.

Comment: A better conclusion, I think, would be that it is somewhat dangerous to use names from `std` without qualifying them.  e.g., `::find(/*etc.*/)` would work here.

Comment: Nitpicky: `std::vector<int>::iterator` can be a class from a different namespace and still have `std` as an associated namespace, because of template and inheritance rules.  For example, my implementation typedefs that type as `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: @James: certainly that would work. I actually meant that it's somewhat dangerous to *define* a name from `std` in another namespace, because someone might call it unqualified. If all calls are going to have to be `::find`, then I might as well call my function `x_find` instead of `find`. Of course there's an issue that you don't know what future standards will add to namespace `std`, so taking caution to its logical conclusion: never make unqualified calls with arguments that could be in a namespace you don't control, unless you want ADL.

Comment: @aschepler: thanks. Is there a straightforward way to express what's an associated namespace, or shall I gloss over the details? ISTR that if `T` is in namespace `foo`, then `foo` is part of the ADL lookup of an argument of type `bar::class_template<T>`, but I don't remember all of it.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: What exactly does `::find()` mean? Does this tell the compiler to only use matches from the global namespace?

Comment: @SteveJessop: Your example is correct.  There are lots of ways to say true things about "if something, then namespace is associated", but practically impossible to give converse statements without quoting all of 3.4.2p2.

Comment: @tajmahal: Yes, typing `::identifier` tells the compiler to only look in the global namespace (and its `using` declarations and directives), just like `N::identifier` tells it to only look in `namespace N` and its `using`s.